# Deploy Maven artifact to remote file system

Tags: maven, deployment, sftp

I have a jar that I am packaging in Maven, that is outputted to my target directory.

I want to put that jar to remote file system (via ssh or sftp) as part of the build process. 
I have tried several methods, but nothing seems to work quite right. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at [wagon-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html). But it sounds like you are trying to do things with Maven for which it is not intended.

Comment: you want to just copy it to remote system or you want to put it to remote repository?

Comment: I strongly recommend using a maven repository like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) or [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) for artifact archiving. If you need to "install" your artifact on a server (e.g. for testing) I recommend building a script that downloads the artifact from the repository or even using a CI Server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). This does no only allow you to decouple your Maven build from your server infrastructure (directories etc), but also enables many more future possibilities and a cleaner setup.